# Permissions on secondary internal HDD

Tags: mount, permissions

So I recently reinstalled ubuntu on a computer at work and now I am setting up the secondary internal HDD. I followed the directions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive) for mounting the drive (the drives was already formatted into two partitions and had data on them so I only had to mount them). Everything went fine, except for permissions on the drives. I followed the instructions of changing the group of the drive to plugdev and the chmod lines below that. Myself and the only other user currently on the computer are both in the plugdev group. But I still have to use sudo to do a lot of things on the drive (was compiling q-chem earlier and had to sudo all of the commands that I normally wouldn't).

I'd like to get this figured out, and to make sure that any time a new user is added to the computer that they will automatically be given permissions for the drive. I know I can probably just chown the drive, but I am not sure if multiple users can own the drive at the same time, and I don't want to have to do that every time a new user is created. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You can make a group and then stick all of those users that you want to be able to access that drive in it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use thunar to access the permission for the mount, and set it to be read/write for everyone, as this seems to be what you are looking for?  Probably will need to sudo your way into thunar to give yourself privs to change the privs on the mounted location, so fair warning.

Comment: Does Nautilus not have the same option? I just use the default file manager.

Comment: I'm on XUbuntu, so my default is Thunar.  I'd bet Nautilus can do the same thing.